# Retrieving an API response in multiple pieces using multiple WS requests in Play Framework

Tags: scala, rest, playframework

I need to retrieve some data from an API endpoint that caps the return size limit at 1 MB.  The data I need to retrieve is larger than 1 MB, so I need to get it in multiple chunks and put it together at the end.  If I only have 2 chunks, I know I can do something like:

```
    val futureResponse: Future[String] = for {
      chunk1 <- ws.url(api_base + "/read")
        .withQueryString("offset" -> 0.toString, "length" -> 1E6.toString)
        .get()
        .map { response =>
          val raw_data = (Json.parse(response.body) \ "data").as[String]
          val decoded_data = Base64.getDecoder.decode(raw_data)
          new String(decoded_data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        }
      chunk2 <- {
        ws.url(api_base + "/read")
          .withQueryString("offset" -> 1E6.toString, "length" -> 1E6.toString)
          .get()
          .map { response =>
            val raw_data = (Json.parse(response.body) \ "data").as[String]
            val decoded_data = Base64.getDecoder.decode(raw_data)
            chunk1 + new String(decoded_data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
          }
      }
    } yield chunk2
```

but the number of chunks will be different from one dataset to another.  Assuming I know the number of chunks that I will need to read, is there any way to use some kind of forEach comprehension to chain an arbitrary number of WS requests together?

Comment: what does the API endpoint return when there is no more data/chunks available? Based on that you have to recusively call the API.

Comment: probably use a loop to call the API as many time as needed, and append the results? for instance, reading the result as bytes